# Как зарегистрировать аккаунт разработчика в google play console без подтверждения личности?

Tags: google-play-console

Как зарегистрировать аккаунт разработчика в google play console без подтверждения личности? Может есть отдельные страны где это не требуют

Comment: я никак не смог. Денег не берут. Видимо надо банковскую карту из соседней страны.
В итоге моё приложение попало только на https://global.developer.mi.com/ но и через него как-то криво устанавливается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если коротко, то никак.

Подробнее:
Подтверждение личности требуется не страной, а самим Google.
Это является частью политики безопасности компании и в первую очередь направлено на защиту пользователей и самой платформы от недобросовестных разработчиков (Google в первую очередь говорит о спаме, но, разумеется, речь идет и о возможном вредоносном ПО и т.д.).